# BubbleSort python swap in two directions

Tags: python

an example of Bubblesort algorithm with python
this algorithm sorts the elements of the list in two directions

```
def bubbleSort_UpDown(alist,ite):
    up=True
    d=0
    f=len(alist)-1
    while d<f :
        if up==True :
            for i in range(f):
                ite+=1
                if alist[i]>alist[i+1]:
                    alist[i+1],alist[i]=alist[i],alist[i+1]
                    f-=1
            up=False
        else:
            for i in range(f,d+1,-1):
                ite+=1
                if alist[i]<alist[i-1]:
                    alist[i-1],alist[i]=alist[i],alist[i-1]
                d+=1
            up=True
    print("debut",d)
    print("fin",f)

    return ite

L=[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]

print("UnSorted list:", L)
iterr=bubbleSort_UpDown(L,0)
print("Sorted list:", L)
print(iterr)
```

iterr print numbers of swap

Question: how can i improve this algorithm. and optimize the number of swap?

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: how can i improve this algorithm. and optimize the number of swap

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bonjour, votre code est bon! Going back to english now, some small fixes needed:

The f-=1 and d+=1 need to move indentation.

The ranges need to change to (d,f,1) and (f,d,-1)

Final Code:

```
def bubbleSort_UpDown(alist,ite):
    up=True
    d=0
    f=len(alist)-1
    while d<f :
        if up==True :
            for i in range(d,f,1):
                ite+=1
                if alist[i]>alist[i+1]:
                    alist[i+1],alist[i]=alist[i],alist[i+1]
            f-=1
            up=False
        else:
            for i in range(f,d,-1):
                ite+=1
                if alist[i]<alist[i-1]:
                    alist[i-1],alist[i]=alist[i],alist[i-1]
            d+=1
            up=True
    print("debut",d)
    print("fin",f)

    return ite

L=[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]

print("UnSorted list:", L)
iterr=bubbleSort_UpDown(L,0)
print("Sorted list:", L)
print(iterr)
```